# Return string from Javascript to razor page using JSInterOp

Tags: javascript, blazor, interop

How I return `string(tmppath)` from `index.js` file and set it in result variable of `OnAfterRenderAsync`. I would like the below `@result` variable to hold the result string

Index.razor:

```
<p>@result</p> // result should be displayed here

@code {
    
    private string? result;
    private DotNetObjectReference<FetchData>? objRef;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {      
       objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
       result = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("Create", objRef);    }
    }
    
    [JSInvokable]
    public string GetMessage(string passedName) => $"Hello, {passedName}!";

    public void Dispose()
    {
        objRef?.Dispose();
    }
```

Problem is first Create function in index.js returns the string "SomeString" to Razor page. But when I use second Create function, it does not return tmppath to razor page.  May I know where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Index.js:

```js
    function Create(dotNetHelper) {
      var str= "SomeString"
      return dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetMessage', str);
    }
```

```
function Create(dotNetHelper) {
  $('#file').change(function (event) {
     //var tmppath= URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
     var tmppath= "blob:https://localhost:44302/784a5c06-c647-432c-b62d-74067f9ddddd"
     console.log(tmppath); // prints in console
     return dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetMessage', tmppath);
 });
}
```

Comment: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I also gave a similar answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574712/is-it-possible-to-alter-the-value-of-a-parameter-within-a-blazor-component-using/72576328#72576328). You just need to add a parameter in the Blazor function to store the path and add `tmppath` as a second argument in the `dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync`.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine thanks a lot for the link. I was able to pass simple string from js to razor page successfully.  But  the same does not work for second create function. Can you advice where I am going wrong. I have edited question with new code.

Comment: If you execute `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("Create", objRef);` on every render, you are going to add a new JS event which might duplicate those. You should execute something like `$('#file').off();`. Secondly,  are you sure the `change` event is triggered?

Comment: Yes change event is triggered and prints tmppath in console. Tried using $('#file').off('change', function (event) {} and $('#file').off( function (event) {
}. Couldn't get to work. And FYI, only second Create function is used in my code. Not first create function (which is added only for comparison). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt your code from the Microsoft example because your `Create` function will not return the result because `Create` sets an event handler.

You need to set `result` in your `[JSInvokable]`, do not go back to JS.

```
[JSInvokable]
public void SetResult(string path)
{
  result = path;
  StateHasChanged();
}
```

No need to return anything in the change event handler:

```
function Create(dotNetHelper) {
  $('#file').change(function (event) {
     //var tmppath= URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
     var tmppath= "blob:https://localhost:44302/784a5c06-c647-432c-b62d-74067f9ddddd"
     console.log(tmppath); // prints in console
     dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SetResult', tmppath);
 });
}
```

There is no result to get from `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>`:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{      
  objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
  await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Create", objRef);
}
```

You still should make sure you don't duplicate the change event handlers on every render, however, you might not see its effect if you don't.

Comment: Not setting result in [JSInvokable] was the problem.  Works perfect now. Thanks a lot.